# Android Fragment: Overlapping - still visible after replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a Fragment (PokedexFragment.java) which contains a GridView (via Custom Recyclerview) with a few items. When I click on an item the current Fragment will be replaced by another fragment (SinglePokemonFragment.java) with the details from the selected item.
The user would like to go to the last or next item in the gridview directly (pressing Forward- / Backbutton). When he presses the Hardware "Backbutton" the old Fragment (SinglePokemonFragment.java) is still visible!

I do not like to use addBackStack, because there should not be any backstacks.

What part of the code is wrong or has to be updated and why?
I thought replace means replace...

SinglePokemonFragment.java (Buttons)

```
cLayBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new SinglePokemonFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putInt("POKEMON_ID", Integer.parseInt(db.getPokemonID(intPokeDexID-1)));
        bundle.putInt("ARRAY_ID", intPokeArrayID-1);
        bundle.putInt("POKEMON_ID_MAX", getIntPokemonIDMax);
        bundle.putInt("POKEDEX_ID", intPokeDexID-1);

        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

    }
});

cLayForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new SinglePokemonFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putInt("POKEMON_ID", Integer.parseInt(db.getPokemonID(intPokeDexID+1)));
        bundle.putInt("ARRAY_ID", intPokeArrayID+1);
        bundle.putInt("POKEMON_ID_MAX", getIntPokemonIDMax);
        bundle.putInt("POKEDEX_ID", intPokeDexID+1);

        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
});
```

MainFragment.java (with ViewPager)

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView titleTxtView;
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private String mParam1;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        if (viewPager != null) {
            Log.v("ViewPager", "IS NOT NULL");
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_pokedex);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.pokedex_kanto);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.pokedex_johto);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.pokedex_hoenn);
        }else{
            Log.v("ViewPager", "ISNULL");
        }



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        myContext=(FragmentActivity) activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity());
        adapter.addFragment(new PokedexFragment().newInstance(0, 9999), "Alle");
        adapter.addFragment(new PokedexFragment().newInstance(1, 151), "Kanto");
        adapter.addFragment(new PokedexFragment().newInstance(152, 251), "Johto");
        adapter.addFragment(new PokedexFragment().newInstance(252, 386), "Hoenn");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

PokedexFragment.java

```
package com.spicysoftware.goexpert;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class PokedexFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    MySQLiteHelper db;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private int param1, param2;

    public PokedexFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            param1 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
            param2 = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    public static PokedexFragment newInstance(int intDexFrom, int intDexTo) {
        PokedexFragment fragment = new PokedexFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, intDexFrom);
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM2, intDexTo);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: 2F");
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pokedexall, container, false);
        db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)myView.findViewById(R.id.rvPokedex);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),4);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

        CustomRecyclerAdapterPokedexGrid adapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapterPokedexGrid(getActivity(), db.getPokemon(param1,param2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return myView;
    }

}
```

CustomRecyclerAdapterPokedexGrid.java (ItemClickListener)

```
viewHolder.setClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {

                if (isLongClick) {

                } else {

                    String test = strPokemonInfo.get(i);
                    String[] separated = test.split("/");
                    intPokemonID = Integer.parseInt(separated[0]);
                    pokeDexID = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);

                    Fragment myFragment = new SinglePokemonFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putInt("POKEMON_ID", intPokemonID);
                    bundle.putInt("ARRAY_ID", i);
                    bundle.putInt("POKEMON_ID_MAX", strPokemonInfo.size());
                    bundle.putInt("POKEDEX_ID", pokeDexID);

                    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
                    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                }

            }
        });
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2015/08/16/how-to-avoid-fragments-overlapping-due-to-backstack-nightmare-in-android/

Comment: @SqueezyMo I already tried that. It's not working: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633598/android-fragments-overlap-eachother/55649322#55649322

Comment: Also, you can do think, set you fragment layout background is white and put clickable true of root layout of fragment